# Turning a 1-D Array into a 2-D Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have to convert about three hundred *1x10000* matrices into *100x100 matrices* in the console with JavaScript.  What is the most efficient way to split each matrix into a *100x100* matrix?  I assume I need to somehow find the 100th instance of a `,` (comma) and replace that comma with `], [`. I am just learning programming here.

```
var myArray = [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, ... ]
```

Comment: is the order of items important?

Comment: Do you have that statement as a string? Otherwise you can't use string manipulation methods on an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy thing to do with `Array.slice`:

```
var myMatrix = Array();
for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    myMatrix.push(myArray.slice(i*100, (i+1)*100));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = new Array();
var index= 0;
for (var i=0; i<100; i++)
{ 
    for (var j=0; j<100; j++)
    { 
       newArray[i,j] = myArray[index];
       index++;
    }
}
```